# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression - on dynamicly added WP Media Upload Button

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plupload

Hello StackOverflow Coders,

got a Problem here with a little jQuery Function im using inside WordPress WP Admin.

I coded a Custom Metabox in which I am having a main Section with an Media Upload Button and the option to dynamically create more Sections, each with an Media upload Button. Everything works, except that when using the Upload Button on one of the dynamically added Sections, the Image Filepath always gets inserted into the first+static Input Field instead of the target one. Also, Chrome Inspector spits out the Message

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression #additional_image_path_additional_134223

**#additional_image_path_additional_134223** is the ID of the Input field next to the Upload button. (the integer at the end gets created dynamically)

This is the Function I am using, so that the Thickbox for the Image Upload gets called on the static Button + the dynamically created ones:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(document).on('click', '.image_uploader_button', function(){ 
        var this_button_id = this.id; 
        var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
        wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment){
            //$('.upload_image').attr('src', attachment.url);
            //$('.custom_media_id').val(attachment.id);
            $('#additional_image_path_' + this_button_id).val(attachment.url);
            wp.media.editor.send.attachment = send_attachment_bkp;
        }
        wp.media.editor.open();
        return false;       
    });
});
```

**Note:** The Element IDs are all correct. The Function just cant target them somehow? Are they somehow out of Scope or something, because they were dynamically added?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE - PROBLEM SOLVED**
So my Function was working correctly, but this function, that was generating the random ID was the problem. I dont know why, but I will hopefully find it out!

```
function uniqid(){
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    var k = Math.floor(Math.random()* 1000000);
    var m = String.fromCharCode(n)+k;
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the line that's throwing the error? That code looks fine...

Comment: Yes, everytime I click the dynamically created Button it throws the same Error. I am also very confused about it...

Comment: Ok, I found the problem... It was NOT inside this function, but inside the function that was generating my Unique ID for the Input Fields. I dont know why. Gonna post another Topic to hopefully learn why this function was giving out numbers that destroyed everything!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE - PROBLEM SOLVED**
So my Function was working correctly, but this function, that was generating the random ID was the problem. I dont know why, but I will hopefully find it out!

```
function uniqid(){
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
    var k = Math.floor(Math.random()* 1000000);
    var m = String.fromCharCode(n)+k;
    return m;
}
```